# Does git pull after init remove untracked files?

Tags: git

I just made a simple script and created a new repository for it on GitHub. After initializing the local repo, moving the script to the repository and `pull`ing the GitHub repository (containing only a `README.md` file), the script was gone. Is this normal behavior? And is there some way to restore the file?

Here are the commands, as executed:

```
$ mkgithub ~/dev/cr2meta2jpg
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/dev/cr2meta2jpg/.git/
$ mv test.sh ~/dev/cr2meta2jpg/cr2meta2jpg.sh
$ cd ~/dev/cr2meta2jpg/
$ ls
cr2meta2jpg.sh
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From github.com:l0b0/cr2meta2jpg
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
$ ls
README.md
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `git pull` will not overwrite local changes unless you use `git add` before. Even in this case, you can still recover your data.

When you issued `git add` before the pull:

```
mkgithub blub
cp test.sh blub/
cd blub/
git add test.sh
git pull
```

The pull will delete `test.sh`. It will only do this if you have no commit in the local repo. After adding a commit this won't remove `test.sh` (git either ignores it or reports a merge conflict)

The file is not lost. It's still in the Git repository as a dangling blob.

To recover the file:

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (401/401), done.
dangling blob 541060d8292ff808c9715265d063f1bae220da7c
$ git show 541060d8292ff808c9715265d063f1bae220da7 > test.sh
```

This works as long as you did not issue `git gc --prune=now` afterwards.

Comment: You can also issue ```git fsck --lost-found```. This will save the dangling blobs to ```.git/lost-found/other```. Either way, the file names are lost. The filenames will be the hashes of the objects.

Comment: This saved a lot of work! 
Had a bunch of changes ready for PR, so created the new branch locally but accidentally issued "git pull" prior to creating the remote branch, this deleted all the work!

Comment: Thanks! Tested this case with fresh git version (2.x) and could not reproduce file loss. Possible issue related only to 1.x git version

Answer (score 0):

I tried making a new repository with a github remote:

```
$ mkgithub ~/dev/cr2meta2jpg
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/dev/cr2meta2jpg/.git/
```

I stuck a file in the folder without tracking it:

```
$ mv test.sh ~/dev/cr2meta2jpg/cr2meta2jpg.sh
$ cd ~/dev/cr2meta2jpg/
$ ls
cr2meta2jpg.sh
```

And then tried to pull from github:

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From github.com:l0b0/cr2meta2jpg
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
$ ls
README.md
```

`cr2meta2jpg.sh` was deleted, so it looks like the answer is yes.

Comment: Only a copy of code from your shell is not really an answer. Can you maybe at some more info?